# ref:Android Application class not destroyed when last activity is destroyed and handler thread destroy

Tags: android

i have the same question posted in "Android Application class not destroyed when last activity is destroyed".

my problem is i have a singleton which i create in the mainactivity oncreate , the singleton among other things create my handlerthread for database writes. in the ondestroy  of the mainactivity i'm killing my thread. when i press the back button to quite the app,the thread it dies no problem there , but next time i select the app since the singleton is still present my thread is not started and all subsequent db writes fail.

what approach should i take here

should i just check on a write attempt if the thread is alive and if not create it again(hope this will not cause any problems) or ? thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

ive gone for a  if((sOrganizerManager.mDatabaseThread == null) ||( !sOrganizerManager.mDatabaseThread.isAlive()))
        {
            sOrganizerManager.mDatabaseThread =new OrganizerDatabaseInsertThread (c,sOrganizerManager);
            sOrganizerManager.mDatabaseThread.start();
            sOrganizerManager.mDatabaseThread.getLooper();
            Log.d(TAG,"Background db thread started");
        }

check on my singleton get function this gets rid of my db write problems. but im not sure if this ok. like i said i'm using mOrganizerManager.destroyDbThread(); on my main onDestroy. I hope there are no lurking problems in this approach, like maybe some partially destroyed zombie threads:)